# How to convert openposes 2d keypoints to 3d

Tags: pose-estimation, openpose

I'm using this code to get keypoints from a video frame, how can I convert the keypoints from openpose to 3d using only 1 camera so I can later make an animation in blender out of them.

```
try:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        raise e
    
    datum = op.Datum()
    datum.cvInputData = frame
    opWrapper.emplaceAndPop(op.VectorDatum([datum]))

    # Check if poseKeypoints is not None before accessing it
    if datum.poseKeypoints is not None:
        # Extract keypoints from the datum object
        keypoints = datum.poseKeypoints
        joint_names = op.getPoseBodyPartMapping(op.PoseModel.BODY_25)  # Get joint names

        # Assuming `keypoints_with_names` is a dictionary
        keypoints_with_names = {joint_names[i]: point.tolist() for i, point in enumerate(keypoints[0])}

        return keypoints_with_names, datum
    
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit(-1)

return None, None
```